# tcc "lvalue expected" error

Tags: c, lvalue, tcc

Sorry for the probably ridiculous and basic question (I haven't programmed in C since I was a teenager, and I'm 39 now...), but with the code below I get the output from the tcc compiler:

```
test.c:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
test.c:26: error: lvalue expected
```

Why is this happening on line 26?

Thanks for your patience, I mainly do web front and back end stuff these days...

----- CODE -----

```
#include <stdio.h>
// needed for gets() and puts()

char* input() {

    char inp[256];

    gets(inp);

    return inp;
}

void output(outp) {

    puts(outp);
}

int main() {

    int exe = 1;
    char inp[256];
    char exit_msg[] = "END OF PROGRAM. THANK YOU!\0";

    while(exe) {

        inp = input(); // line 26
        output(inp);

        if (inp == "END"){

            exe = 0;
        }
    }
    puts(exit_msg);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's so much wrong ...

1. Don't use `gets`, ever. It's been removed from C because it's impossible to use safely. (If the input is too long, you have a buffer overflow on your hands.) You could use e.g. `fgets` instead.
2. `input()` returns the address of a local variable. Local variables are destroyed when they go out of scope, i.e. when `input` returns. The return value is always garbage.
3. `outp` is missing a type. Looks like you're getting implicit `int` from your compiler (implicit `int` has been removed from C in 1999).
4. String literals are implicitly NUL-terminated. `\0` doesn't do much in `"END OF PROGRAM. THANK YOU!\0"` (except making sure there are two NULs at the end).
5. You cannot assign to arrays in C. `inp = ...` is invalid. Check out `strcpy` and `memcpy`. (Even if you could assign to arrays, `inp = input()` would be a type error because `input` returns a pointer, not an array (but you can't return arrays).)
6. `inp == "END"` compares pointers. `inp` will never have the same address as a string literal. Check out `strcmp`.
7. Why does `exe` exist? Instead of setting `exe = 0`, you could just `break` out of the loop.

(#5 is the one your question is about.)

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate forthwith. I appreciate that someone took the time to answer...

Comment: I tried while(1) and using both "break" and "continue" to leave the loop, they both compiled under tcc, but both crashed after "input()", seemingly on execution of "output()".... I'm aware continue is wrong, but I tried it anyway when break; failed....